# ActionBarSherlock using ( api ver. 4 / android 1.6)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-sdk-1.6

I want to use ActionBarSherlock with api ver.r 4 ( android 1.6 ). I set proper build target and I got errors :

> Error:(104, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:104:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'. Error:(4, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml:4:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'. Error:(73, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:73:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'. Error:(29,
>   -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:29:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
>   Error:(70, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:70:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
>   Error:(33, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:33:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'. Error:(51, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:51:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionMode'. Error:(38,
>   -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:38:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
>   Error:(4, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:4:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'. Error:(63, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:63:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'. Error:(78, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:78:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'. Error:(96,
>   -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:96:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'. Error:(90, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:90:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'. Error:(89, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:89:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:dividerPadding'. Error:(22, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml:22:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:windowActionBar'. Error:(119, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:119:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'. Error:(110, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:110:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
>   Error:(68, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:68:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
>   Error:(17, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:17:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
>   Error:(75, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:75:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow'.
>   Error:(183, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:183:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:showDividers'. Error:(83, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:83:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
>   Error:(88, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:88:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
>   Error:(117, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:117:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'. Error:(309, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:309:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:textAllCaps'. Error:(58, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:58:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'. Error:(26, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:26:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'. Error:(6, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:6:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
>   Error:(121, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:121:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'. Error:(15, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:15:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
>   Error:(108, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:108:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'. Error:(36,
>   -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:36:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'. Error:(65,
>   -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:65:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'. Error:(8,
>   -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml:8:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
>   Error:(85, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:85:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'. Error:(46, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:46:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
>   Error:(22, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:22:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
>   Error:(24, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:24:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
>   Error:(88, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:88:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:showDividers'. Error:(8, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:8:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
>   Error:(6, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v11/abs__themes.xml:6:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:windowActionBar'. Error:(6, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml:6:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'. Error:(43, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:43:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'. Error:(10, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:10:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
>   Error:(26, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml:26:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:windowActionBar'. Error:(113, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:113:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu'.
>   Error:(214, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:214:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:spinnerMode'. Error:(115, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:115:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'. Error:(19, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:19:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'. Error:(60, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:60:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
>   Error:(106, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:106:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
>   Error:(80, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:80:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar'.
>   Error:(93, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:93:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml
>   Error:(258, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:258:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:animationResolution'. Error:(55, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:55:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
>   Error:(10, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v11/abs__themes.xml:10:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:windowActionBar'. Error:(14, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml:14:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v11/abs__themes.xml
>   Error:(41, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:41:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
>   Error:(53, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:53:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode'.
>   Error:(101, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:101:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:textAllCaps'. Error:(4, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v11/abs__themes.xml:4:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'. Error:(98, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:98:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
>   Error:(31, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:31:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
>   Error:(100, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:100:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'. Error:(102,
>   -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:102:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml
>   Error:(184, -1) android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml:184:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:dividerPadding'. Error:(12, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:12:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'. Error:(8, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v11/abs__themes.xml:8:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'. Error:(48, -1)
>   android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock]
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:48:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
>   /Users/jacekchronowski/Android/AppetizeSDKParam/actionbarsherlock/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml

My question is there any chances to make it working?

**EDIT:**
Maybe some solution will be to use older version of ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: `any chances to make it working?` **NO**. ABS is compatible with API Level 7+. Consider that Eclair is used by **less than the 0.1%** of the current android devices all over the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you changed the library compile or target api level,you must set api level 11+ for library and set api level 4 for your project.

Comment: Ok, so which older version supports api ver. 4 ( android 1.6) ?

Comment: I don't understand why you use api level 4,I think first you must check platform version distribution : https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html min api is 8 and distribution is 0.7%. This time nobody in the world old version then 14 that does not support.

Answer (score 2):

`any chances to make it working?` **NO**: ABS is compatible with **API Level 7+**.
Also consider that Eclair is used by **less than the 0.1%** of the current android devices all over the world.

Comment: My goal to achieve this compatibility comes from clients requirements not my own.

Comment: Your customers won't have the ActionBarSherlock. I guess you'll have to make **your own** action bar (a layout with some Views).

Comment: The stuff is more complicated but thanks for replies. Client is not willing to change goals and requirements

Comment: But ActionBarSherlock is **not compatible** with API Levels **lower than 7**. And so isn't ActionBarCompat. So, as per your question (`api ver. 4 / android 1.6`), your customer won't have any standard ActionBar.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock 3.5.1 works with api ver.4 and supports all needed features. You just have to remember not to include android-support-v4.jar in any project. ABS ver. 3.5.1 includes it.

Comment: From: http://actionbarsherlock.com/ `allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.` **2.x and up** (2.0 is API Level **5**)

Comment: Abs 3.5.1 minSdk is 4 and I have tested it